# VB Access 2010 Parse Delimited Row to Column

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Function splitWords(ByVal strLine)

Dim ParsedStrLine() As String

ParsedStrLine = Split(strLine, ", ")

For i = LBound(ParsedStrLine) To UBound(ParsedStrLine)
    splitWords = ParsedStrLine(i)

Next

End Function
```

I know next to nothing about VB.
I am trying to write a function that takes in a csv field and appends back to the same table in a different column.

```
THIS
someTable:
col_1 col_2
a     x, y, z

TO THIS
someTable:
col_1 col_2
a     x, y, z
x
y
z
```

Let me know if you need anymore information.

Comment: You do not show any delimiter in "xyz", yet the title mentions one. Is there a delimiter?

Comment: edited, they are comma delimited fields, when I run this all i get back are the last elements in each array, kind of like the array can only hold one element. I am better at Java, for about 2 minutes I had strLine.split(", ") on a line wondering what was wrong.

Comment: Also, there is not always 3 items in col_2 there will be at least 2, up to 15-20 sometimes for each record, so the array needs to be dynamically written and read.

Comment: they will always be different numbers for each query. col_1 is like a container number for col_2 numbers. I have to export these as xml and load them and i need all the numbers to be in col_1, I am having to cut and paste to excel and sort columns then cut and paste back to the access table.

Comment: yes, there will be many records, i was trying to make the function to enter as an expression in an append query. So if anyone has any other suggestions, put em down and i will try them at work tomorrow, thank you for your quick response too.

Answer (score 0):

For just one row:

```
ParsedStrLine = Split(strLine, ", ")

For i = LBound(ParsedStrLine) To UBound(ParsedStrLine)
    splitWords = ParsedStrLine(i)
    CurrentDB.Execute "INSERT INTO tbl (Col1) VALUES ('" & splitWords & "'")
Next
```

But you may wish to work with the whole recordset.

```
Dim db As Database
Dim rs As Recordset
Dim rsAdd As Recordset

Set db = CurrentDb

Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Col_2 Is Not Null")
Set rsAdd = db.OpenRecordset("Table1")

Do While Not rs.EOF
    ary = Split(rs!col_2, ", ")
    For i = 0 To UBound(ary)
        rsAdd.AddNew
        rsAdd!col_1 = ary(i)
        rsAdd.Update
    Next
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```